# What is the secret operator?

Tags: number-property

There is a secret operator $F$ that takes two whole numbers and outputs a new number. For example

$$\begin{split}F(6,9) &= 15\\
F(66,11) &= 110  \\
F(86,18) &= 179\end{split}$$

Can you find what $F$ does and what is the output of $F(601,81)$ ?

Hint:

> F may not be defined for all inputs

Comment: I LaTeXed your question!

Comment: does F always produce whole, positive integers when given whole numbers? Because if not, you can always solve $F(x,y)=ax + by + c$ for a,b,c and get a very, very ugly result.

Comment: @subrunner What if it is a non-linear operator? I suspect there is some concatenation involved.

Comment: Given the description, $F$ sounds more like a function than an operator.

Comment: operator, function, that is pretty much the same, isn't it? an operator is a function of 2 dimensions! And yes, it is probably a non-linear operator, but if you make no restrictions on what F can output it COULD be the simple but ugly solution!

Comment: An operator is a special type of function which maps functions to functions. You would not call a function that maps integers to integers an operator.

Comment: @brady-gilg The word operator has several meanings, and you'd have to settle on one to make an exact distinction. In computer language design, for example, operator generally means "function of one or two variables that is written in a prefix or infix form". Thus `-` is a unary operator because `-x` applies the operator to the variable `x`, and  `+` is a binary operator because `x+y` applies the operator to x and y.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answer could be:

> Rotating the whole numbers, rather parameters, and not the individual integers, by 180 degrees and adding them together.
>
>  $F( 6, 9) \quad\rightarrow  9 +  6 \quad=  15$
>  $F(66,11) \rightarrow 99 + 11 = 110$
>  $F(86,18) \rightarrow 98 + 81 = 179$

Therefore the output of $F(601, 81)$ would be

> $109 + 18 = 127$

Comment: +1 for sheer mindbending non-mathematical genius! Now I know why the question wasn't tagged 'mathematics' :)

Comment: Hi Ewasted and welcome to Puzzling! It would improve your answer to be more specific about what 'flipping' means in your answer. If you could explicitly mention *rotation* instead in your answer it would be much clearer. (To me, flipping 601 could mean either (i) reversing the digits to 106 or flipping each individual digit across its horizontal axis  to get 901 - neither of these is quite what you mean!) Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now :-)

Comment: You got it. Well done!

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, here's the solution as a short C# program. No string operations necessary :)

> ```
> void Main()
> {
>   F(6,9).Dump();      //  15
>   F(66,11).Dump();    // 110
>   F(86,18).Dump();    // 179
>   F(601,81).Dump();   // 127
>  }
>
>  int F(int x, int y)
>  {
>   return rotate(x)+rotate(y);
>  }
>
>  int rotate(int num)
>  {
>   int result =0;
>   for (; num > 0; num /= 10)
>   {
>       int digit = num % 10;
>       switch (digit)
>       {
>           case 0: case 1: case 2: case 5: case 8: break;
>           case 3: case 4: case 7: throw new ArgumentException($"can't flip {digit}");
>           case 6: digit = 9; break;
>           case 9: digit = 6; break;
>           default: throw new ArgumentException("I can't even");
>       }
>       result = result * 10 + digit;
>   }
>   return result;
>  }
> ```

Comment: Really nice.  Could the 'rules' be changed so the number remains as is if it can't be rotated?

Comment: Sure, although that goes against the Hint at end of the question here.  But if you want: just change the line with `can't flip {digit}`, replacing the word `throw` and everything after it with `break;`

Comment: I didn't see the hint at first.